# Implementing custom iterator in struct for custom linked list type

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I have a linked list using std::list, that is of custom type "node" `(std::list<node>)` which is implemented through

```
struct node {
    std::string pname;
    int time;
};
```

I am wondering how I can create an iterator so that I can loop through my linked list to be able to print out the contents of 'pname' and 'time', or if the creation of a custom iterator is not needed to do so, would like to know how that could be done. Thanks!

Comment: `for (auto&& n : list)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Something a bit like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct node {
    std::string pname;
    int time;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<node> nodes {
        {"test 1", 1},
        {"test 2", 2},
    };

    for(auto& n: nodes) // range-based for
        std::cout << n.pname << ": " << n.time << '\n';

    // iterator 
    for(auto iter = std::begin(nodes); iter != std::end(nodes); ++iter)
        std::cout << iter->pname << ": " << iter->time << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
test 1: 1
test 2: 2
test 1: 1
test 2: 2
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Works exactly as I need.